# Spring bean injection without explicit dependency declaration?

Tags: java, spring, aop, javabeans

I was working for a few months on the project without even noticing this, and yesterday, after editing a class file (inserting new dependency bean with its getter/setter), I forgot to explicitly add:

```
<property name="deviceService" ref="deviceService"/>
```

in the appropriate spring context xml.
I publshed my web app to tomcat, entered debug, and the moment I saw the line of code using this service bean, I realized that I forgot to declare it as the dependecy.
But then, strange thing happend - the bean was injected nevertheless...
This behaviour confuses me a bit. I'm surely not a spring expert, I've been using it for the past several months, however this is not something that I expected to be possible. The name of the class field, as it can be seen, is the same as bean that is being injected, if that matters. In the debugger I saw something like this for the dependency field:

```
deviceService=$Proxy5 (id=107)
   * h=JdkDynamicAopProxy (id=147)
```

so I'm guessing it has to do something with spring AOP.

I must add that I didn't start this project form scratch, it was already configured, it uses spring-aop for transactions demarcation, and some logging purposes.

**EDIT**
Some additional info: project integrates ZK Ajax and Hibernate as well. This service bean is basically a wrapper around a DAO bean; DAO bean is in turn a wrapper around spring's HibernateTemplate. Service and DAO beans are singleton-scoped. Service that is being injected is injected into the prototype-scoped MVC controller bean. Service bean is from the package used for DB transaction demarcation:

```
<tx:advice id="serviceTxAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
    <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="serviceMethodsRMS"
        expression="execution(* org.irvas.amregina.backend.service.*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="serviceTxAdvice" pointcut-ref="serviceMethodsRMS" />
</aop:config>
```

So, can anyone explain to me what is going on, or what could be the reason for this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the root beans tag of the xml there is an attribute **default-autowire-byname** / **default-autowire-bytype**.  If that is set to true then spring will inject the dependencies automatically.  By default it is set to false - I am guessing that in your case one of the above flag is set to true.

AOP is not involved in dependency injection. You are seeing the proxy because the object that is being injected is using some feature of spring that needs aop (like transaction , security etc).

Comment: OK, it's got to be something about autowiring, but I just checked all my configs, none of them has _default-autowire_ or _autowire_ attribute set (they are not present inside the beans/bean tags), so it uses some kind of default. It is really strange, because I expect "no" as the default setting... :)

Comment: What is even worse, I explicitly set in all 4 of my context config files _default-autowire="no"_, and _autowire="no"_ for dependent bean. Injection still works... I should again say that this service class is from the package that is set in aop pointcut expression for transaction demarcation. <aop:pointcut id="serviceSysMethods"
   expression="execution(* org.irvas.amregina.backend.service.*.*(..))" />

Comment: You can put a break point in the setter method and look at from where the call is coming. If it can't be run in an IDE you could log the stacktrace (create an exception & log it). That should throw some light on how this is happening.

Comment: Thanks gkamal, call stack shows that it has something to do with ZK's component composer - it does some kind of Filed wiring. I'll accept your answer, even though it seems this goes out of bounds of spring-related issues.

Answer (score 1):

Check for one of the following in your configurations .

context:annotation-config or context:component-scan along with

1. [@Autowired](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation) annotation along with @Component on spring beans for autowiing by type .
2. [@Resource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-resource-annotation) annotation which does autowiring by name + @Component in your spring beans as you have not defined any beans in the spring configuration. You sping beans will have the first letter of the classname lowercased .
3. default-autowire="bytype" as @gkamal has discussed.
4. default-autowire="byname" + an @Component.
5. default-autowire="autodetect".

Comment: The only annotation I use is @Secured.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of autowiring: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire